# jquery mobile .listview() adding only last item to localstorage regardless of item clicked

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile, local-storage, jquery-mobile-listview

I am dealing with dynamic list. here is the mark up and the html used to display it.

```
 markup += '<li><a href="#fbfullpostviewpage" id="addPostToLocalStorage" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-overlay-theme="e" data-inline="true"><img src="' + thumb_url + '">' +'<h4>' + name + '</h4><p>' +'posted this photo....</p><p>'+likes+'<img src="images/facebook-like-16.png"></p></a></li>';
```

this is inside a loop, so it does it for every list item. and after the loop I have an

```
$('#newsfeedposts').append(markup);
$('#newsfeedposts').listview("refresh");
```

however, when each item on the list is clicked, I want to add it to local storage.
 right after the above code I do this,

```
 $('a').bind('click', function(){
         localStorage.setItem("fbclickedPost", JSON.stringify(post));
         console.log(post);
         alert("this post was added to local storage");

        // showDetailedPost(post);
        var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("fbclickedPost");
        var facebookPost2 = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
         console.log(facebookPost2);
```

it works and logs to console the array item, however the issue is that regardless of what item is clicked on the list, it always adds only the last item on the list to local storage but I want to add the current item that is being clicked on, to local storage.

any help would be great please! I've been struggling for long now.

Comment: Yea you are overwriting fbclickedPost value each time you click, quite not sure what you ar trying to achieve with the code you have got.

Comment: You cant have the same ID for all list items `id="addPostToLocalStorage"`. Also to attached a listener to a dynamically created item use `$(document).on('click', 'a', function ()`

Comment: what is `post`? where are u getting it from?

Comment: ^ here's the code for the function. This function queries the facebook stream and displays the post in list view. When an item is clicked a dialog is opened(which is a new page in jquery mobile) I don't understand why its adding only last item to local storage regardless of which item is being clicked

Comment: @manraj82 http://pastebin.com/qhZfdun3

Comment: Ive sorted it! it works now

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add the click event to the link elements `<a>` before adding them to your `listview` (just after creating them):

**In your LOOP, do the following:**

```
new_markup = $('<li><a href="#fbfullpostviewpage" id="addPostToLocalStorage" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-overlay-theme="e" data-inline="true"><img src="' + thumb_url + '">' +'<h4>' + name + '</h4><p>' +'posted this photo....</p><p>'+likes+'<img src="images/facebook-like-16.png"></p></a></li>');

// Add the click event to the link <a> :
new_markup.children('a').click(function(){
     localStorage.setItem("fbclickedPost", JSON.stringify(post));
     console.log(post);
     alert("this post was added to local storage");

    // showDetailedPost(post);
    var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("fbclickedPost");
    var facebookPost2 = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
     console.log(facebookPost2);
});

$('#newsfeedposts').append(new_markup);
```

**Then, after your LOOP, when it's over, refresh your `listview`:**

```
$('#newsfeedposts').listview("refresh");
```

Let me know if this works mate.

Comment: " markup.children('a').click(function()" doesnt seem to work, it says the item has no method children. that could be because markup is a single element and has no sub elements on it?